# Can you sum moments about a point not on the object?

Tags: forces, reference-frames, rotational-dynamics, torque

Do you have to sum moments about points on an object, or can moments be summed around an object as well.  For example, [image]

This is what someone did in my statics class to help find the reactions on part of a frame.  H is not on any other part of the frame.  Can you do this?  Are there any restrictions to this technique?

Comment: Why were Cort and my posts down voted? This was clearly a conceptual question not seeking a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sum the moments around any point and get the correct results.  Summing moments and summing forces are actually mathematically equivalent.  You just have to integrate everything properly (basically summing over every particle).  Some problems are easier to solve with moments, others are easier to solve with momentum.

What's happening here is no more strange than trying to do math on a doughnut, where the CG is actually hanging out in empty space in the middle of the hole.  (which, frankly, is pretty weird, but the math works out!)

The one thing you have to remember is that the moment of inertia will be different if your calculate moments around a different point.  In statics, you wont have to worry about this, because the sum of the moments is always zero.  In dynamics, this is a bit more of a pest.

Comment: "Some problems are easier to solve with moments, others are easier to solve with momentum" Moments and momentum? How are these equivalent? And how are summing moments and forces mathematically equivalent? They are two separate static equilibrium requirements. It's like saying forces and torques are the same thing.

Comment: @BobD Momentum and angular momentum are related, just operating on systems with different symmetries.  That is why you can solve for a circular orbit of a point mass using conservation of linear momentum, and why you can solve for what happens to a car which loses traction in a corner using angular momentum as it moves in a straight line.  The only time they really have to be treated differently is when you have a rigid body and wish to handle all of its degrees of freedom without integrating over a set of points with all of the associated particles.

Comment: I agree with everything you said in the context of dynamics. My answer was in the context of statics and static equilibrium. In statics I would  not consider moments to be equivalent to angular momentum since the moments involved in statics sum to zero so that there is not rotation. Similarly, in statics forces do not equate to linear momentum because the sum of the forces are necessarily zero. So I really don't see any disagreement here. BTW what do you think of the down votes? I don't see post as an H&E seeking a solution to a particular problem. To me its a conceptual question.

Comment: @BobD I think it works in statics as well.  However, solving statics problems by integrating/summing over lots of point masses is typically not how you do it.  The whole point of statics is to get to assume enough to avoid such calculations.  As for the downvote, I'm not a fan of the downvote, but I can see why.  If you note from our discussion, I had to take a bit of a stab in the dark.  The question does clearly state what the OP wants, but there's not quite enough information to really pin down what part of the process the OP took enough issue with to ask the question.

Comment: Personally, I don't like to downvote questions in the form of "Why does this technique work," because I like people to ask questions rather than blindly assuming things work.  But different people downvote for different reasons.  StackExchange is not 100% clear on when to downvote, and I think they are smart in leaving it a bit open ended.

Comment: And when it comes to statics, a lot of the "why" answers comes from taking it out of the statics realm, seeing how the basic Newtonian physics works, then bringing it back into statics with the corresponding constraints.  And then *greatly* appreciating how much the great minds before you shortcutted the process so you don't have to do the massive blocks of differential equations yourself!

Comment: Amen to all of that. BTW, curious about your tag ("Reinstate Monica").

Comment: @BobD She was a well respected moderator that Stack Exchange stripped of her moderator status.  Many consider their actions unjust, and beyond that there are further questions about libel that have been raised.  I like to direct people [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334399/summing-up-the-main-issues-the-story-so-far/334417#334417), which is the community's efforts to write down what happened in as unbiased of a form as they can manage, and then people can decide their own stance.

Comment: We are, of course, a bit in the dark.  Due to legal issues, the involved parties are no longer talking to the community (a very reasonable move which is typical in such scenarios).  The situation may resolve itself amicably.  I, for one, hope it does.